# Hikari DataSource returns null in Spring Boot if auto-commit=false

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm moving a project from tomcat-jdbc to hikari. I migrated configurations, but it behaves different in the following case.

The following function is called in an IT test. (db. Oracle 11g)

```
Long id= jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select vehicles.create_vehicle(?,?) from dual", Long.class, ...);
```

When using tomcat-jdbc, it returns id a non-null value. It is expected, but when I switched to hikari, it returns null.

In both cases are auto-commit=false.

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=false
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

I suspected from isolation-level, but both are isolation-level=2 when I check the actual JDBC connection.

When I change auto-commit to spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=true , it works in hikari, but I don't understand, why does hikari behave different than tomcat-jdbc? Do I miss something?

Comment: you should see some logs like this `Resetting autocommit to false on JDBC Connection [HikariConnectionProxy(1313459755) wrapping com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@6482eef]`

Comment: Let's say I see some logs like this? I didn't get your point.

Comment: You should see the difference when you have true and by default hikari leaves that to jdbcdriver @UsTa

Comment: Tomcat-jdbc also leaves it to driver. I set auto-commit property explicitly. tomcat-jdbc reads data but hikari doesn't read when both has auto-commit=false. I ask this difference.